# Javascript querySelector to iterate over matching objects and use .innerHTML on them?

Tags: javascript

I've been using the following code to iterate over matching elements in the DOM. But this apparently does not work if I want to use something like .innerHTML or .innerText.

```
  let courseList = document.querySelectorAll(".course");
  for (let course of courseList) {

    course.querySelector('.course-number').innerText("Test");

  }
```

Those objects I'm trying to iterate over look like this:

```
<div class="course">
    <div class="course-number">1</div>
</div>
<div class="course">
    <div class="course-number">2</div>
</div>
```

I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: course.querySelector(...).innerText is not a function(…)`

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: `course.querySelector('.course-number').innerText = "Test";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `innerText` and `innerHTML` are not functions whereas there are properties. So, value should be assigned to them as below.

```js
let courseList = document.querySelectorAll(".course");
  for (let course of courseList) {

    course.querySelector('.course-number').innerText = "Test";
    //course.querySelector('.course-number').innerHTML = "Test";

  }
```

```html
<div class="course">
    <div class="course-number">1</div>
</div>
<div class="course">
    <div class="course-number">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb. Thanks for the help. :)